# change git commit message and keep SHA the same

Tags: git, sha

Since a git SHA is a hash generated from the commit files, metadata, and commit message, changing the commit message changes the SHA.

But would it be possible to make a change to the commit message that preserves the SHA, by 'balancing out' the change to the message with some random string at the end, which cancels out the change to the original message?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Practical application (were this feasible): suppose your comments refer to issues in your tracker by URL, and these are all about to change.

Comment: It seems from the answers here you'll need to find a workaround.

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to find a collision for the SHA1 hash algorithm, which is only possible by a brute force attack needing a lot of computing power to test all possible paddings.

Some analysis on this can be found here:
https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2012/10/when_will_we_se.html

They write:

> A collision attack is therefore well within the range of what an
>   organized crime syndicate can practically budget by 2018, and a
>   university research project by 2021.

"Normal" people should better try their luck in gambling. ;)

If you are interested in even more details, please ask at http://crypto.stackexchange.com as this question is really about cryptography and not about git.

Answer (score 3):

In theory this is possible — there probably exists some padding that would preserve the SHA1 sum.

In practice this is extremely hard — SHA1 is a cryptographically secure hash function, which means that things like what you propose cannot be done practically (*non-malleability*). If they could, SHA1 would be a poor cryptographic hash.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, but it takes time. Prepare to spend the next few years on trying different paddings until you get a matching SHA.

Provided your check-in allows you to add a character without changing the semantics of the check-in (comments, optional whitespace; what have you), try adding one more and see what the resulting hash is.

Expect to need to try again a few times. SHA1 is 160 bits so you should plan on spending a significant fraction of 2^160 times (approx 1.46e48).

Comment: This is really just a tongue-in-cheek paraphrase of @michas' excellent answer.